# How to do a PySpark/SQL join on multiple columns with condition of being latest (by Timestamp)

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am attempting to join two tables. The top table has many more rows than the bottom table, and consists of a unique sender id, timestamp, sender account ids, and receiver account ids. I want to join this table with a smaller table, which has (generic) account codes, which match to either the sender account or receiver account in the top table (it could be either one depending on the row of this smaller table). I want to join the tables on these codes, with the joined table containing two new columns: the first indicating labels that matched to the sender account, and the other indicating labels that matched to the receiver account.

Where this gets interesting (and by interesting I mean difficult) is that some records in the top table have intermediaries, i.e. Account A sends to Account B sends to Account C (all initiated by the same unique sender). Among these records with intermediaries, the receiver account labels column should should show the label for the *final* receiver account (final meaning the last row, which means it is the one with the latest timestamp). All unique senders can be identified with the id column (this is *not* an index column) in that they will have the same id across intermediaries.

Since I am using PySpark the join could be performed using either PySpark syntax or SQL syntax.

I am using PySpark 3.3.0

Current:

```
+---+-------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|id |Timestamp          |SenderAccount         |ReceiverAccount       |
+---+-------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|1  |2022-01-01 00:00:01|A394840               |*A290375*             |
|2  |2022-01-01 00:00:01|A943200               |A176108               |
|3  |2022-01-01 00:00:02|A139480               |A091392               |
|1  |2022-01-01 00:00:02|*A290375*             |*A293491*             |
|4  |2022-01-01 00:00:03|A109347               |A123948               |
+---+-------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+------------------+-----+
|Account           |Label|
+------------------+-----+
|A394840           |A3   |
|A176108           |B7   |
|A139480           |B9   |
|*A293491*         |*A2* |
|A290375           |B6   |
+------------------+-----+
```

Desired:

```
+---+-------------------+-------------+---------------+--------------+----------------+
|id |Timestamp          |SenderAccount|ReceiverAccount|SenderAccLabel|ReceiverAccLabel|
+---+-------------------+-------------+---------------+--------------+----------------+
|1  |2022-01-01 00:00:01|A394840      |A290375        |A3            |*A2*            |
|2  |2022-01-01 00:00:01|A943200      |A176108        |A9            |B7              |
|3  |2022-01-01 00:00:02|A139480      |A091392        |B9            |A2              |
|1  |2022-01-01 00:00:02|A234870      |A293491        |B7            |*A2*            |
|4  |2022-01-01 00:00:03|A109347      |A123948        |B6            |A8              |
+---+-------------------+-------------+---------------+--------------+----------------+
```

Comment: could you please share   more data on the same ?
Could you explain the how the senderAccount 
for the record id=1 and timeStamp="2022-01-01 00:00::02" has "A234870"

Comment: Try use Window function , you can easily solve this .

Comment: Thanks, I will look into window functions.
As far as the relationship between records/ids, timestamps and the flags, it doesn't matter as far as the join. The SenderAccount and ReceiverAccount codes are just identifiers. They could be anything.